# Swap elements an arraylist when meets a specific condition

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist = `[1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] or [0,1,1,3,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0]`

I want it to be = `[1,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0], or [1,1,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0]`

The algorithm is **not just swap the collections**, but need a condition.

So total elements of an array are always can divided by the max value itself

eg. `array[]=[1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` contains 2 as max value, therefore total elements can divide by 2, so it has 5 element as each condition.

Then the array should be sorted by the min to max value inside it. 
After that put zero value as the rest of 5 element

Now it should be `[1,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0]`

already implemented :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // contains 1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
   if( i == list.size() - 1){
      newList.add(list.get(i));
      break;
   }
   if(list.get(i).equals(0) && list.get(i+1).equals(0)){
      break;
   } else if(!list.get(i).equals(0) && list.get(i+1).equals(0)){
      newList.add(list.get(i));
      break;
   }

   if(!list.get(i).equals(list.get(i+1))){
       newList.add(list.get(i));
       for(int j=0; j < 4; j++){     **// <== only added 4, not the rest of elements**
          newList.add(0);
       }
   } else {
       newList.add(list.get(i));
   }    
}
```

result: newList contains 1,0,0,0,0,2

expected result: newList contains 1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0

Please advise,

Thank you.

Comment: `int i ==0` - a typo?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to find a **question** in that question text. Or even a problem description. What is your issue? If the code runs, what isn't work as expected? What result do you actually get, vs. what did you expect?

Comment: It would seem that `array` and `newArray` are not actually **arrays**. *(Hint: An `ArrayList` is not an array, it's a `List`)* Please include [Minimal, Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ok thanks, will modify it

Comment: isn't that my code...? it doesn't work however

Comment: then, how is the correct one? @GauravMall

Comment: I don't know, because this code works. It was you who said that this was not exactly what you wanted. So, I left it upon you to customize the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows:

```js
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0));
            
        System.out.println("Output1: " + getOutput(list));
        
        list = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(0,1,1,3,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0));
            
        System.out.println("Output2: " + getOutput(list));
     }
     
     public static List<Integer> getOutput(List input){
         
         List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
         
         Collections.sort(input); 
         
         Map<Integer, Integer> elementsCountMap = countFreq(input, input.size());
         int zerosCount =  elementsCountMap.containsKey(0) ? elementsCountMap.get(0) : 0;
         int nonZerosCount = (zerosCount == 0) ? elementsCountMap.size() : elementsCountMap.size() - 1;
         int addingZeroCount = zerosCount/nonZerosCount;
         boolean isOdd = (addingZeroCount > 0) && (zerosCount % addingZeroCount == 0) ? false : true;
         boolean isZeroAdded = false;
         
          for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : elementsCountMap.entrySet()) 
        { 
            if(entry.getKey() != 0){
                
                for(int j = 0 ; j < entry.getValue() ; j++)
                    output.add(entry.getKey());
                    
                if(addingZeroCount > 0){
                    for(int j = 0 ; j < addingZeroCount ; j++)
                        output.add(0);
                    if(isOdd && !isZeroAdded)
                        output.add(0);isZeroAdded = true;
                }
            }
              
        } 
        
         return output;
     }
     
     static  Map<Integer, Integer> countFreq(List arr, int n) { 
        Map<Integer, Integer> mp = new HashMap<>(); 
  
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            if (mp.containsKey((int)arr.get(i)))  
            { 
                mp.put((int)arr.get(i), mp.get((int)arr.get(i)) + 1); 
            }  
            else
            { 
                mp.put((int)arr.get(i), 1); 
            } 
        } 
        
        return mp;
    }
}
```